# Grunt-init - Making an HTTPS request on template.js

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, scaffolding

On a Grunt-init template I would like to create a node.js https request. **Is that possible?**

Grunt-init console says: 
`Warning: Protocol:https: not supported`

Here is the code I am trying to add

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream("file.txt");
var request = http.get("https://someurl.com/file.text", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `https` module.  It acts just like the `http` module, with a few differences that only matter when you want to check certs.  See the [node https docs](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html) for details.

In your example you can just replace `require('http')` with `require('https')`.

You probably don't want to worry about which protocol to use for every url you want to fetch, so you might want to look into a higher level library: the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library is very popular, although there are [many others](https://npmjs.org/search?q=http+client).